# Abstract Calendar Designer App

Tags: android, calendar, android-app, app

I am looking for an app called abstract calendar designer.

In this app, you can enumerate, in the top widget, a sequence of "year lengths". You do this by clicking on the add button on the right, which is a square with a plus. The number goes on the left, and is part of a sequence of numbers that can be added in boxes and can be scrolled left or right to view the number of items in the boxes.

Below this, you add the sequence of month lengths. This is done with the same type of widget.

Below this, you input the week length.

Below this is the first calendar daysm's offset within the same week.

The output is a calendar, in a format with the week days W1 ... Wn at the top and the month days M1 ... Mk_y_l in a rectangular array.

With this app, a kid can fiddle and figure out what days would look like, and how they would be numbered, if they appeared in weeks, months, and years, of different for weeks and variable for months and years, lengths.

You can scroll, through the months (and view where each number falls).

This would be a good start for healthy calendar intrinsic nature, construction, and calculation schemes.

You could think more stuff from there.

You could also save different schemes, and compare them, by saving them to a list, and selecting whatever list you wanted, from the three stripe bar on the upper left, which could present the user, with a list of selectable saves.

I think such an app would promote cleverness, number set tackling engineering, and healthy thinking.

I wonder whether anyone could please develop such an app, and make it available on the Google Play store.

I really need it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not an android app, but have you seen [https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/calendar/](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/calendar/)?